# How to understand what mere (adjective) means in a sentence

Tags: meaning, adjectives

In [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mere_1?q=mere) and [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk/ingilizce/mere) there are two definitions for the adjective 'mere'. Moreover, these two definitions are completely opposite. One means to emphasize unimportance, while the other expresses importance. At least, this is what I drew on. So, how can I understand whether the situation is important or not by interpreting 'mere'? For example;

'Is it really possible that the mere presence of certain actors can doom a TV show?'

There are two possible meanings I believe;

1. There are actors that the audience show contempt for them; so they prefer not to watch the show as the actors are present repeatedly.
2. There are actors that the audience again don't like to see on the TV; however this time they appear less frequent but again the popularity of the show goes down as people don't watch it.

Comment: "mere" is not a verb.  It's an adjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "mere" probably comes from the Latin root "merus" meaning something like pure, or undiluted. From that we get the current meaning which is something like "nothing more than" or "all that is needed". And that can indeed have two seemingly opposing meanings, depending on how it is used. Imagine two brothers racing each other. One beats the other by 1/100th of a second. The loser implies that the 1/100th of a second difference is unimportant:

> A mere 1/100th of a second means we should call it a tie!

But the winner replies by pointing out that the 1/100th of a second can be extremely important:

> A mere 1/100th of a second is enough to have one person go to the Olympics and the other to stay home!

In both, the sense of "nothing more than" is seen in the way the brothers appear to be agreeing that 1/100th of a second is small. The difference is that one feels the smallness means it can be ignored, whereas the other sees it as being critical.

In your original, the meaning is like that of the losing brother. The small (pure, undiluted) thing is the presence of certain actors and the questioner, through that word "really", is finding it hard to believe that something so small could be important. So the original:

> Is it really possible that the mere presence of certain actors can doom a TV show?

could be re-written as:

> Really? Are you serious? Is it really possible that **nothing more than the** presence of certain actors is important enough to doom a TV show?

And then the answer could come back, now using the same meaning of "mere" as the winning brother:

> Absolutely. It is absolutely possible that **all that is needed** to doom a show is the presence of certain actors. That's how important it is.

So I can see why the dictionaries have those two definitions, but it is a bit confusing because they are sort of saying the same thing. The meaning of "mere" used in this way is always something like "nothing more than", but that can be used to indicate unimportance or importance depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence

> Is it really possible that the mere presence of certain actors can
> doom a TV show?

says (when expanded)

> This TV show  was doomed. No one watches it. Could that be just
> because it featured certain actors, or would there have to be other
> reasons?

Definition from Oxford Languages

> mere
> adjective
>
> that is solely or no more or better than what is specified.
>
> "questions that cannot be answered by mere mortals"

Answer (score 0):

The two definitions you mention aren't really complete opposites. Looking at the definitions you linked from Cambridge, we have:

> used to emphasize that something is not large or important:
> *The plane crashed mere minutes after take-off.*
> *It cost a mere 20 dollars.*

and

> used to emphasize how strongly someone feels about something or how extreme a situation is:
> *The mere thought of it (= just thinking about it) makes me feel sick.
>
> People became excited at the mere mention of his name.
>
> the mere idea/possibility/prospect of something*

The idea in the second definition is that despite the thing being not large or important (as in the first definition) it can cause the effect mentioned. If you say "Is it really possible that the mere presence of certain actors can doom a TV show?" you're asking if even something as small as just having certain actors present will doom the TV show. Your possible meanings aren't really correct, as the question doesn't give us any more information - it's suggesting the presence of the actors alone might be enough to doom the show, but isn't giving us any information about why that might be the case.